# Передать значение ключа в массив

Tags: java, дата, calendar

Доброе утро. Пишу функцию календаря, где есть 2 аргумента месяц и год. Функция возвращает 2мерный массив и строит календарь на определенный год.
Сравниваю localDate с ключем, если совпадает возвращаю значение. Как мне его передать что бы строился правильно мой календарь?

```
package lang;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class GetFunWithJavaLang {

public static int[][] Cal(int month, int year) throws IOException
{

    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);

    System.out.println(localDate.getDayOfWeek());

    HashMap<String , Integer> map = new HashMap<String , Integer>();

    map.put("SUNDAY", 7); 
    map.put("MONDAY", 1); 
    map.put("TUESDAY", 2); 
    map.put("WEDNESDAY", 3); 
    map.put("THURSDAY", 4); 
    map.put("FRIDAY", 5); 
    map.put("SATURDAY", 6); 
    for(Entry entry: map.entrySet()) {

          String key = (String) entry.getKey();
          if (key.equals(localDate))
          {
              int value = (int) entry.getValue();    
          }  
        }
    int[] days = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}; 
    int[][] calen = new int[6][7]; 
    int k=0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i<calen.length ; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0 ; j<calen.length ; j++)
        {   
            if (days[month-1] > k)
            {
            k++;
            calen[i][j] = k;
            }       
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < calen.length; i++, System.out.println("  ")) {
        for (int j = 0; j < calen[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(calen[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }
    return calen;   
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    Cal(1, 1998);   
}   
}
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/R1jVH7 возвращает 5, то есть 5й день недели

Comment: @SeniorAutomator сейчас, как обычно, окажется, что стандартными классами пользоваться нельзя...

Comment: не понял. то есть нельзя щас пользоваться стандартными классами или потом так окажется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите получить день недели для указанной даты. А именно для начала месяца. Это делается очень просто, если использовать новый API для дат:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(1998, 1, 1);
System.out.println(localDate.getDayOfWeek());
```

Вывод будет таким:

> THURSDAY